# Will polymorphic relation cause slowness on big data?

Tags: laravel-5, database-design, bigdata

Good Evening/Morning,

I am developing a social media type database which will have millions of users, I have not worked with a data that big so I am a bit concerned about the approach I am taking with the comments part. There will be comments on different entities such as Posts, Pages, Groups, and 3 to 4 more. So what I am asking is that if anyone out there have implemented polymorphic relation on big data can you share your experience on its performance on big data?

Answer (score 0):

Because you have a single table for different models.

Take the example on Laravel documentation (User and Post can have an Image). If you need to retrieve something like this

`User::find(1)->image`

internally Laravel makes a query similar to:

`SELECT * FROM images WHERE imageable_id = 1 AND imageable_type = '\App\User';`

As you image, if you have a lot of images and imageable_* columns are not indexed, these kind of queries will take a lot of time to run.

So, my suggestion is to try to create a index based on this tuple (imageable_id, imageable_type).